# Как можно задать свойства dataSource с помощью XML в SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-jdbc

Допустим есть некий xml файл с конфигурацией `dataSource`:

```
<bean id = "dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name = "driverClassName" value = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test;create=true"/>
    <property name = "username" value = "1"/>
    <property name = "password" value = "2"/>
</bean>
```

Есть классическое CRUD приложение на SpringBoot'e с использованием `jdbcTemplate` которое автоматически подтягивает cвойства для подключения к бд из `application.properties`.

**Вопрос в следующем:** могу ли я как то использовать свойства из XML файла заместо `aplication.properties` либо как то явно ссылаясь на свою xml конфигурацию и что для этого нужно сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать аннотацию `@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")`:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
public class SpringBootXmlApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired 
    private Pojo pojo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootXmlApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Шире можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-xml-beans).

Comment: Да, это в полной мере решило мой вопрос, спасибо!